# Chartkick Timeline (time blocks)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

Is it possible to use Chartkick timeline to display timeline of a day?

For example to have something like this:

```
<%= timeline [
  ["Monday", "00:00:00", "02:00:00"],
  ["Tuesday", "05:00:00", "10:00:00"]
] %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array passed to timeline has to be in following format:

```
[["Monday", "0000-00-00 00:00:00", "0000-00-00 00:15:00"],
 ["Tuesday", "0000-00-00 01:05:00", "0000-00-00 04:00:00"]]
```